# How can I test the significance of a non-linear function of regression coefficients in R?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

Let's say I have an equation $Y = \beta_0 +  \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + ... + \beta_k X_k $, where $\beta_i$ represents an estimated coefficient and $X_i$ represent independent variables. How can I test whether the function $\beta_1/\beta_2$ is significantly different from zero?

Comment: Do you mean to ask a question about coefficients rather than the independent variables?

Comment: Have a look at package lmtest or car.

Comment: For constructing confidence inertvals for ratio's see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164738/confidence-interval-of-ratio-estimator/164745#164745.  Note that form a confidence interval you can derive a hypopthesis test.

Answer (score 4):

Note that -- as long as $\beta_2$ is not zero -- if $\beta_1=0$, then the ratio $\beta_1/\beta_2$ must logically be zero, so if you reject $\beta_1=0$ you can reject the ratio being $0$.

More generally, there's a nifty trick you can do with ratios (again keeping in mind that this only works as long as $\beta_2$ isn't exactly 0):

$H_0: \beta_1/\beta_2=k$

is equivalent to

$H_0: \beta_1=k\beta_2$

so you can test such a ratio simply by testing the linear restriction:

$H_0: \beta_1-k\beta_2=0$